# Create a list of actions based on probability of each action

Tags: python, probability

I have 3 actions and their probabilities:

> walk:5
>
> talk:1
>
> run:2

I need to do ALL of them.

But the most important action should be(but not must) executed first and ONLY ONCE.

So walk has 5 times more chance to be executed before talk.

Also I can't run if walk has never been executed before.

My current solution is expensive but it works. Now I compose a list and the first action will be inserted at the beginning of the list:

```
actions_poll = ['walk']*5 + ['run']*2 + ['talk']*1
flow_control= []
while len(flow_control) != 3:
    action = roll one action from action pool
    if action not in flow_control:
       * check if action is run and walk is in flow control
       flow_control.append(action)
```

I guess using a list with amount in actions_poll is not the best way, also trying again and again the loop can run for a long time when walk is 5000 and talk is 1.

Suggestions?

Comment: you can probably use `random.choices([list of choices], [list of probabilities for each])`
(python 3.6 or 3.7)

Comment: You can't RUN without WALK. So WALK should always have more probability. Explore Bayes' rule in this regard. After that you can do exponential smoothing giving them ranking based on their probability and then executing them.

Comment: why `flow_controls` needs to have max size = 3?

Comment: did you mean, maybe `len(set(flow_controls)) == 3`?

Comment: I don't understand this `But the most important should be(but not must) executed first and ONLY ONCE`. What do you mean as "most important"? The one that have the major probability?

Comment: 3 is the number of actions, it does not have limit.

Comment: "But the most important should be(but not must) executed first and ONLY ONCE"
I need to order them by probability but, walk don't have to be always first just in most cases ...

Comment: if you write `while len(flow_control) != 3` it will stop after three insert. I don't understand this part. Because you said that it does not have a limit, but ...it does! I think that you meant `len(set(flow_controls)) != 3` (every action needs to be at least once in the list)

Comment: No, each action will be only once at the list.
So no need for set

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.random.choice` to sample the actions according to their probabilities (using the parameter `p=`) and `set` to check that all actions has been sampled, like this

```
import numpy as np

actions = ['walk', 'talk','run']
weights = np.array([5,1,2]) 

flows_control = set()
flows_decision = []
while len(flows_control) < len(actions):
    action = np.random.choice(actions, p=weights/weights.sum(), size=1)[0]
    flows_control.add(action)
    flows_decision.append(action)
```

---

If you want your `flows_decision` to be a list of unique decisions, simply do:

```
np.random.choice(actions, p=weights/weights.sum(), size=len(actions), replace=False)
```

Comment: shouldn't you pop the action from actions list each time it inserted ?
and what about performance ? I still see a while loop of len condition which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: If you don't want the loop and you don't want doublon in your list of actions, you should go for the second solution I proposed. I tried with 10k different actions, it lasts a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: BTW, if you have hard constraint such has "cant' `run` if `walk` has never be seen before", I don't see other solution than the loop, plus adding test variables (bool or dict) to assert if a given actions has been sample before. And you could also use those test variables to append action in your flow only if there new.

Comment: but issue is when one action is so tiny in prob it can loop for seconds!